# Does eduroam block tor?

Tags: bridge

I've experienced difficulties connecting to Tor from eduroam.  Does eduroam block tor?  Would this be simply an artifact of the institution through which I tried to use eduroam?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is likely caused by the institution you are connecting to, and not eduroam.

I have never used eduroam (nor heard of it before this post), but after viewing their documentation it appears they only integrate with other institutions for RADIUS authentication (https://www.eduroam.us/node/10). Meaning they really only care about figuring out if you belong on their network or not.

After you are authenticated your traffic is controlled by the institution you are at.